# Strip layer from mulitdimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am having some difficulty manipulating the below array.  I have tried various things and I feel like there should be a simple way to achieve this, but I cannot seem to figure it out.  Any tips or help greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Color] => Blue
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Size] => S
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Color] => Blue
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Size] => M
                    )

            )
)
```

My desired outcome is:

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                  [Color] => Blue
                  [Size]  => S
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                  [Color] => Blue
                  [Size] => M        
            )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
$items = array(
    array(
        array("Color" => "Blue"),
        array("Size" => "S")
    ),
    array(
        array("Color" => "Blue"),
        array("Size" => "M")
    )
);
$new_items = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $collect = array();
    foreach ($item as $values) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $collect[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    $new_items[] = $collect;
}
var_dump($new_items);
```

Your array is 3 deep, so you need at least 3 nested loops.

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Color"]=>
    string(4) "Blue"
    ["Size"]=>
    string(1) "S"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Color"]=>
    string(4) "Blue"
    ["Size"]=>
    string(1) "M"
  }
}
```

Comment: I was stuck trying loops with two foreach...thank you for explaining and posting code!

Comment: It's normal, because nested loops are quite unreadable, go and check my solution.

Answer (score 2):

2 loops are enough with array_merge

```
$a = array(
    array(
        array(
                'Color' => 'Blue'
            ),
        array(
                'Size' => 'S'
            ),
    ),
    array(
        array(
                'Color' => 'Blue'
            ),
        array(
                'Size' => 'M'
            ),
    ),

);

$c = array();

foreach($a as $b)
{
    $ca = array();
    if(is_array($b))
    {
        foreach($b as $array)
        {
            $ca = array_merge($ca, $array);
        }
        $c[] = $ca;
    }
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($c,true);
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that `array_merge` does a loop too (only faster).

Comment: It's a good idea to always use built in functions when avaliable. Its really not the same if it's a php or a C loop. ( If you care about speed and code quality )

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_map for this:

```
<?php
function combine($elementArray)
{
    return array($elementArray[0]["Color"], $elementArray[1]['Size']);
}

$originalArray = array(
        0 => array(
                0 => array("Color" => "Blue"),
                1 => array("Size" => "S")
        ),
        1 => array(
           0 => array( "Color" => "Blue"),
           1 => array("Size" => "M")
        )
);


$combinedArray = array_map("combine", $originalArray);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($combinedArray);
?>
```

Also you can use anonymous functions and do it like a pro ;)

```
$combinedArray = array_map( 
    function($element){
        return array(
            "Color" => $element[0]["Color"],
            "Size" => $element[1]['Size']
       );

    },$originalArray);
```

Or you can even use array_reduce example:

```
$reducedArray = array_reduce($originalArray, function($result, $item){
    $result[] = array(
        'Color' => $item[0]['Color'],
        'Size' => $item[1]['Size']
    );
    return $result;
});
```

Comment: If readability is a concern, you can improve your `combine` function by using an `array_reduce`. The reason you want to use `reduce` here is because it's a very clear indication what is going on: you're _removing one level_. Also a minor note: your implementation doesn't preserve the keys (`Color` and `Size`)

Comment: Thanks for noticing the error. IMHO & btw as more as I look at the both implementations I find the array_map implementation more explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
    $array = 
    array(
        array(
            array(
                'color'=>'Blue'
            ),
            array(
                'size'=>'s'
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                'color'=>'Red'
            ),
            array(
                'size'=>'m'
            )
        )
    );
$mA = array();
foreach($array as $k=>$a){
    array_push($mA,array_merge($a[0],$a[1]));
}

var_dump($mA);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I believe this will generate an error though array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: i got the response array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'color' => string 'Blue' (length=4)
      'size' => string 's' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'color' => string 'Red' (length=3)
      'size' => string 'm' (length=1)